# How to picking broken glass out of gravel, in the rain

Tags: glass

Picking up glass on big gravel stones in the rain. How do I pick up the tiny glass shards on the big gravel stones in the rain?  I can't find a better day to pick the glass up because I am busy.

Comment: This is a suggestion instead of an answer, and I don't know if you'll like it. But since broken glass is dangerous, I would remove all the gravel and glass, and replace it with new gravel. Otherwise there is a danger that in the coming days-weeks-months, a person or animal will get cut and may even have a shard of glass embedded under their skin.

Comment: As I have experience doing this, I usually walk across the gravel barefoot, then pull the shards out of my feet.  This works best if the person walking doesn't know the glass exists...  Of course, I don't recommend this, it's just my own experience in a similar situation.

Answer (score 2):

Use a screen that has holes smaller than the gravel, and then sift the glass out.